# How to start MySQL server in Docker container made on a base mysql/mysql-server

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to make a docker image based on mysql/mysql-server .
I have an app (golang) which should use MySQL to store data. I want to run this app in a docker

My Docker file looks like

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD rootpass
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydb
ENV MYSQL_USER dbuser
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD dbpass

ADD myapp / # compiled colang app connecting to localhost:3306 mysql server
CMD ["myapp"]
```

I build this image and run it and have error

```
docker run --name mycont -it myimage
dial tcp [::1]:3306: getsockopt: connection refused
```

**What is wrong here?**

Maybe i have to start mysql server somehow before to execute my app?

My app tries to connect to mysql on  localhost:3306 with the user dbuser/dbpassword and database mydb. Then will create some tables in the DB

Comment: Well running two processes in a docker container is normally not the way to go. You would create a docker-image for your app and use the mysql image separately. You would use some tool for orchestrating (docker-compose, kubernetes) to spin up those images to a working app. If you really want to run both processes in the same container, you have to write a "wrapper" script which would start mysql in the background an then your app as a "main-process".

Comment: Mentioned by @vstm , what you wish to deploy is really not the best practice. Do you just wanna know how to run multiple processes in one container, or you want a best solution on your scenario?

Comment: I want to make my app to be easy to run by "not a guru" in docker. Ideally, i want to prepare one single command for my users who wants to try the app to run it with docker. If there is orchestrating  tool, a user will have to install it first.
Is it possible to prepare some sort of complex image to run such kind of pp with one single command?

Comment: @RomanGelembjuk, if you want to achieve that on a Linux OS then it is pretty simple. Write a shell script that would perform all the steps: install docker and docker-compose, run docker-compose passing the yaml file that I showed in my answer. Make sure you published your app on the docker hub before running the script. So, this approach will require some work on your side, but your users would only need to run that script. I don't know how could that be achieved on Windows though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible to achieve that, but it would not be considered a good practice. The recommended approach would be to run two different containers: one running mysql and the other one running your application. Besides that, you would need an orchestration tool to run the containers.

So, with the risk of getting a few down-votes :-), instead of directly answering to your question and showing how to create a single container that would run both functionalities, I prefer to show the two-container approach that I consider a better practice.

In my example I use docker compose for orchestration. You will need to install it if you haven’t done it already.
Below is the `docker-compose.yml` file that I used to run the two containers:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysqlserver:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpass"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mydb"
      MYSQL_USER: "dbuser"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "dbpass"

  myapp:
    image: myimage
    environment:
      MYSQL_SERVER: "mysqlserver"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mydb"
      MYSQL_USER: "dbuser"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
```

The file defines two services: `mysqlserver` and `myapp` which will be run as separate containers. Each of the two services define two elements:

- the `image` used for creating the container
- the `environment` variables passed to that container

The `mysqlserver` service has two extra properties defined:

- `command`, which specifies the extra parameters passed to mysql service at runtime. To cut the story short: that `--default-authentication-plugin` is necessary for mysql 8. Try to run the container without it and you might end-up with some connection errors. You can read more about that on the official mysql docker page.
- `ports`, which specifies what container ports are exposed to the outside

Now, let’s define your app image. I don’t speak golang but I prepared a simple example using Linux shell script.

`myapp` code would be the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ">> Waiting for $MYSQL_SERVER to start"
while ! `nc -z $MYSQL_SERVER 3306`; do sleep 3; done
echo ">> $MYSQL_SERVER has started"

mysql --host=$MYSQL_SERVER --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --database=$MYSQL_DATABASE<<EOFMYSQL
drop table if exists test;
create table test(id int, name varchar(20));
insert into test values (5, 'a'), (12, 'b');
select * from test;
EOFMYSQL
```

The app will first run `nc` command in a while loop, checks that status of the mysql server every 3 seconds and only exits the loop when the `mysqlserver` has fully started and accepts connections on port 3306. We need to make sure that the database server is running before trying to connect to it, right?

Once the server has started, the `myapp` connects to it using the credentials passed as environment variables in the docker compose file. After the connection, it runs a few sql statements (delete table, create table, insert, select). 
All those environment parameters could be hard-coded in the code of `myapp` but I think it would be better to pass them in the docker compose file.

The `Dockerfile` used to create `myapp` image is the following:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add netcat-openbsd mysql-client
ADD myapp /
RUN chmod +x /myapp
CMD /myapp
```

I’m usually using alpine linux as a base for my tests as it is very lightweight. I need to run `apk add netcat-openbsd mysql-client` for adding the `nc` and the `mysql-client` to the image. 
Instead of the myapp shell script you will just need to add your golang myapp file.

Now, let’s assemble everything. Do the following steps further:

- put the `Dockerfile` and `myapp` files in the same folder and build the myapp image:

`docker image build -t myimage .`

- run docker compose with the above `docker-compose.yml` file as input:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`

At this moment both containers will start. `myapp` will wait for the `mysqlserver` to be ready and after that it would connect to it and run the simple queries.

I’m not sure how familiar are you with linux, shell scripting, yaml syntax, etc.. but I hope I provided you enough details to get the idea.